# nameserver response not all data returned

Tags: dns, udp, response, nameservers

When I do a request to a nameserver which has dnssec the response is sometimes incomplete
i looked around on the web and found some information regarding the issue
*2.3.4 Size limits*
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035

It says`UDP messages 512 octets or less`

To receive a bigger response I need `EDNS0` so i can receive a max of `4096 bytes.`I can't really figure out how to use/enable EDNS0
*EDNS0 info:*
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2671
**EDIT**
i have to send an OPT RR with my request to get more data back. i have an example from microsoft, but they use a type RRSIG. i want to use a type ANY.
http://img266.imageshack.us/img266/6707/optf.png

**The question:**
can someone explain how EDNS0 works and why my opt rr is not working.(i use the same as the microsoft example)

thx in advance:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some odd reason my request is working now.

Request i send:
`01 01 01 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 01". domain2dns($domainname) ."00 00 ff 00 01 00 00 29 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00`

explanation of the **EDNS** part
`Name: 00

Type: 00 29

UDP Payload size: 10 00

Higher bits in extended RCODE:00

EDNS0 version: 00

Z: 00 00

Data Lenght: 00 00`

NAME - - domain name -- empty (root domain)
TYPE - - u_int16_t ---- OPT
CLASS - u_int16_t ---- sender's UDP payload size
TTL - - - u_int32_t ---- extended RCODE and flags
RDLEN - u_int16_t ---- describes RDATA
RDATA - octet stream - {attribute,value} pairs

Problem solved
thx guys :)